# Prove that $(\ell_2, \|\cdot\|)$ with coordinate-wise product is semisimple

Tags: operator-theory, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be the sequence space $(\ell_2, \|\cdot\|)$ with coordinate-wise product

> Prove that $(\ell_2, \|\cdot\|)$ with coordinate-wise product is semisimple

**My attempt:** I define $\delta_k:\ell_2 \to \mathbb {C}$ by $\delta_k(a_n)=a_k$. Therefore $\delta_k$ is a character (non-zero  homomorphism) and $\ker\delta_k=\{0\}$ but we cannot say $\operatorname{Rad}A=\{0\}$ since $A$ does not have an identity.

Here is where I am stuck. Could you please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: For completeness, include the definition of "semisimple".  I guess from your tags that you are not using that term as in ring theory, but instead as in normed algebra theory.